# run a query while login validation process

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have just started learning codigniter and having some issues now I am trying to convert my core  php to codigniter mvc so the thing is that in normal php I used the following script with following featurs.

```
function verify($connect) {
    $username  = $_POST["username"];
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["password"]);

    $get_query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users");

    while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_query)) {
        $uname = $record{"username"};
        $pass  = $record["password"];

        if($username == $uname && $password == $pass) {
            if($record["utype"] == "admin") {
                $_SESSION["uname"] = $username;
                $_SESSION["uid"]   = $record["uid"];

                header("Location: control.php?uid=".$_SESSION["uid"]);
            } else {
                $_SESSION["uname"] = $username;
                $_SESSION["uid"]   = $record["uid"];

                $query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO online (uid, status, uname) VALUES ('{$record["uid"]}', 'online', '$username')");
                header("Location: index.php?uid=".$_SESSION["uid"]);
            }
        } else {
            $_SESSION["message"] = "Invalid Username/Password provided";
            header("Location: login.php");
        }
    }
}
```

okay so now in mvc i use the following but how do i complete make the same function as above

```
public function login_validation() {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim');

        if($this->form_validation->run()) {     
            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'), 
                'is_logged_in' => 1
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('main/index');
        } else {
            $this->load->view('login');
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can refer http://www.formget.com/form-login-codeigniter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to made following changes in your code

Please look at this code and try to implement by reading comments.

```
public function verify(){

$this->load->library('session'); # load codeigniter session library

# $this->input->post() is used for set post data

$username  = $this->input->post("username");
$password  = $this->input->post("password");

$q=$this->db->get_where('users',array('username'=>$username,'password'=>$password));

if($q->num_rows() > 0){ # num_rows() gets total numbers of record in table

    $result = $q->row(); # Returns single records

    if($result->utype == "admin") {

        # $this->session->set_userdata() is used for set session in codeigniter

        $this->session->set_userdata("uname",$username); 
        $this->session->set_userdata("uid",$result->uid);
        redirect(base_url().'index.php/yourController/method'); # change your controller name & method name

    }else{

        $this->session->set_userdata("uname",$username); 
        $this->session->set_userdata("uid",$result->uid);

        $data=array('uid'=>$result->uid,'status'=>'online','uname'=>$username);
        $this->db->insert('online',$data);

        # $this->session->userdata() is used for retrive session data in codeigniter

        redirect(base_url().'index.php/yourController/method?uid='.$this->session->userdata("uid"));    # change your controller name & method name
    }   
}else{

    # $this->session->set_flashdata() is used for set set message and retrive this flashdata by $this->session->flashdata('message') on your view page

    $this->session->set_flashdata('message',"Invalid Username/Password provided");
    redirect(base_url().'index.php/yourController/method'); # change your controller name & method name
}
 }
```

Hope this code will help you!!!

Comment: Perfect worked for me now I understood the concept thank  you